# Java Simple Christmas tree

Tags: java, for-loop

I am new to java and I have to create a simple java programm that creates a christmas tree in this form:

```
10|       *       |15=7+1+7
 9|      ***      |15=6+3+6
 8|     *****     |15=5+5+5
 7|    *******    |15=4+7+4
 6|   *********   |15=3+9+3
 5|  ***********  |15=2+11+2
 4| ************* |15=1+13+1
 3|***************|15=0+15+0
 2|      ***      |15=6+3+6
 1|      ***      |15=6+3+6
```

The height (all natural positive numbers) and the material ("*" in this case is given by the user input).
This is what I already have, but I dont know how to get the "|15=7+1+7" at the end of each line and the Tree trunk in the bottom of the tree.

Here is my actual code, and what it creates:

```
public class Christmas{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int height = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String letters = (args[1]);
        char firstLetter = letters.charAt(0);

        //System.out.println(height+"   "+firstLetter);     

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
         // System.out.print((args.length)+"");
         int row_number = height-i;
         System.out.printf("%2d",row_number);
         System.out.print("|");

            for (int j = 1; j < height - i; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");  
            }   
                for (int k = 0; k < (2 * i + 1); k++){
                System.out.print(firstLetter+"");
                }

         System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
C:\Users\name\Desktop\JavaFolder>javac Christmas.java && java Christmas 10 *OMEGALUL
10|         *
 9|        ***
 8|       *****
 7|      *******
 6|     *********
 5|    ***********
 4|   *************
 3|  ***************
 2| *****************
 1|*******************
```

How can I add the Tree **trunk which is always 3 letters long and 1/4** of each tree big.(rounded) and the |15=7+1+7 at the **end of each lines which contains:**
The width of the tree as the sum of the spaces left + the width of the tree in the respective row + spaces on the right (left-aligned).

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track. Maybe just have one loop for the height, then have variables for numLeftSpaces and numRightSpaces and you would decrement those each loop iteration. You could have another variable for numAsterisks, and that would increment by two during each loop iteration. If you get that working, you should be able to print the numbers to the right.  For the trunk, it seems fairly simple so keep trying.

Comment: `trunkHeight = treeHeight - (treeHeight * 4) / 5` then `trunkHeight = treeHeight - trunkHeight` in your example, if the total height was 10, then the first bit would calculate the leaves to be 8 and the  trunk to be 2. I'm assuming you can take it from there.

Comment: Just right now I am really trying to get it working but i am sadly just not able to make it working and my deadline is in some hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different approach, which *calculates* the number of `spaces` and the number of `fill` characters needed on a line, then uses `printf` to print the lines.

```
public static void printChristmasTree(int height, char ch) {
    if (height <= 4)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Height must be 5 or higher");
    for (int row = height; row > 0; row--) {
        int spaces = (row > 2 ? row - 3 : height - 4);
        int fill = (height - spaces) * 2 - 5;
        System.out.printf("%2d|%s%s%s|%d=%d+%d+%d%n", row,
                          repeat(spaces, ' '), repeat(fill, ch), repeat(spaces, ' '),
                          spaces * 2 + fill, spaces, fill, spaces);
    }
}
private static String repeat(int count, char ch) {
    char[] buf = new char[count];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(buf, ch);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

*Test*

```
printChristmasTree(10, '*');
```

```
printChristmasTree(6, '#');
```

*Output*

```
10|       *       |15=7+1+7
 9|      ***      |15=6+3+6
 8|     *****     |15=5+5+5
 7|    *******    |15=4+7+4
 6|   *********   |15=3+9+3
 5|  ***********  |15=2+11+2
 4| ************* |15=1+13+1
 3|***************|15=0+15+0
 2|      ***      |15=6+3+6
 1|      ***      |15=6+3+6
```

```
 6|   #   |7=3+1+3
 5|  ###  |7=2+3+2
 4| ##### |7=1+5+1
 3|#######|7=0+7+0
 2|  ###  |7=2+3+2
 1|  ###  |7=2+3+2
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is logic for trunk height of `height/4` *(rounded)*, instead of the fixed height of `2` used by the code above. Trunk width is still fixed at 3.

```
public static void printChristmasTree(int height, char ch) {
    final int trunkHeight = (height + 2) / 4; // rounded
    final int treeWidth = (height - trunkHeight) * 2 - 1;
    final int width = (treeWidth > 3 || trunkHeight == 0 ? treeWidth : 3);
    for (int row = height; row > 0; row--) {
        int fill = (row > trunkHeight ? (height - row) * 2 + 1 : 3);
        int spaces = (width - fill) / 2;
        System.out.printf("%2d|%s%s%s|%d=%d+%d+%d%n", row,
                          repeat(spaces, ' '), repeat(fill, ch), repeat(spaces, ' '),
                          spaces * 2 + fill, spaces, fill, spaces);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
printChristmasTree(5, '*');
printChristmasTree(4, '*');
printChristmasTree(3, '*');
printChristmasTree(2, '*');
printChristmasTree(1, '*');
```

*Output*

```
 5|   *   |7=3+1+3
 4|  ***  |7=2+3+2
 3| ***** |7=1+5+1
 2|*******|7=0+7+0
 1|  ***  |7=2+3+2
```

```
 4|  *  |5=2+1+2
 3| *** |5=1+3+1
 2|*****|5=0+5+0
 1| *** |5=1+3+1
```

```
 3| * |3=1+1+1
 2|***|3=0+3+0
 1|***|3=0+3+0
```

```
 2| * |3=1+1+1
 1|***|3=0+3+0
```

```
 1|*|1=0+1+0
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Works perfect, I just need some minutes to fully understand the code but it looks much more efficient than mine. Thank you, i also upvoted but its not shown because I have less than 15 rep. One question: is there a way to also make it work for a tree with the height between 1 and 5 ?

Comment: @FlazzerXP Since the trunk of the tree is always 2x3, a tree with heights 1 or 2 would be trunk only, and heights 3 or 4 won't *look* like a tree, so any height <= 4 makes no sense to print.

Comment: It's true that it dont look like a tree, but my task says it has to work for all natural positive numbers. And the trunk is 1/4 (rounded,but a trunk must always exist) of the height of the tree, not always 2. Just the width is always 3.

Comment: I must confess that I find the code as a beginner also very complex and hard to understand. Would it be easier to solve with for loops?

Comment: Yes we have a lot of tasks for university to get authorized for exam. I never had any problems with them until now, i really cant find any solution this time.

Comment: @Andreas Okay to make the trunk 1/4 of the tree height we just change  "2" to "(height/4)" on line 16, but what about making it work with height 0 to 4?

Comment: @FlazzerXP You remove the `if` statement and change the calculation logic to correctly calculate `spaces` and `fill` for those values. --- *FYI:* `(height/4)` doesn't *round*, it *truncates*.